# WCF + web api + No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it x.x.x.x:443

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am accessing a third party web api from my WCF application. While development I was able to access those APIs but when I deployed my WCF to IIS, its not able to connect to the web API and throwing me the following error:

"*System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it X.X.X.X:443*"

Just to make sure that my server is fine where I deployed my WCF. I tried accessing those web api from a simple console application. It accessed those apis from my development machine and from the server machine as well. Now I feel the culprit is not the third party web api server, but something goes wrong when a WCF service access' a web-api hosted in IIS.

Please help!!!

Comment: Are you using the same way to access the web api from your wcf application and your console application?

Comment: yes. Code is copied paste!

Comment: In that case it's probably not working due to a different reason. Are you sure the exception is being thrown where you think?

Comment: Yes. I finally found what the issues is. I am posting it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. IIS runs my WCF under user 'network service' or 'application pool identity'. These are nothing but window built-in users which has limited access. When I tried accessing third party API from the console application it worked because it was running under my user credential which has admin credential. So I concluded that when an application making cross-domain call then it should be running under a user with enough credential to make such calls.

Solution was to change my application pool identity to a admin user identity (*I changed it to my logged in user*). It worked and making calls to third party API from WCF service